# TSQL select nearest non-future date range grouped by key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the simplified table structure of `PRICES`:

> ```
> SKU      PriceType    FromDate      ToDate        Price
> ..............................................................
> SUR40    NONMEMBER    1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1000
> SUR40    RSP          1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1500
> SUR40    MEMBER       2012-07-04    2012-07-04    649
> SUR40    MEMBER       2012-06-15    2012-06-15    699
> SUR40    MEMBER       2012-06-01    2012-06-01    599
> SUR40    MEMBER       2012-03-31    2012-03-31    699
> SUR40    MEMBER       1900-01-01    1900-01-01    749
> ```

This `PRICES` table stores all the prices of all products. The `FromDate` and `ToDate` columns specify the period the price should take effect. A null date (returned as 1900-01-01) is the default price should there be no promotions on the date specified.

Given a SKU and a date, the query should return the prices of the product applicable to the date. For example, selecting using 2012-06-16 should return:

> ```
> SUR40    NONMEMBER    1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1000
> SUR40    RSP          1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1500
> SUR40    MEMBER       1900-01-01    1900-01-01    749
> ```

Selecting using 2012-06-15 should return:

> ```
> SUR40    NONMEMBER    1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1000
> SUR40    RSP          1900-01-01    1900-01-01    1500
> SUR40    MEMBER       2012-06-15    2012-06-15    699
> ```

The SQL server is MS SQL 2008 R2. It's been a while since I wrote my last SQL query, I can't seem to get my head around this. :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
select SKU, PriceType, FromDate, ToDate, Price from PRICES
where SKU IN ('SUR40')
and PriceType IN ('NONMEMBER','RSP','MEMBER')
and FromDate < GETDATE()
order by PriceType, FromDate DESC
```

I think there should be a `group by` somewhere, but working with a web service that returns no error messages upon failure is not very helpful :(

Comment: This would be easier were the data model different :) eg just as a first thought, *default* prices should be in a completely different table. Anyway, this is still doable...

Comment: Why does the second query omit the record with price 749. I thought you want to handle `1900-01-01` dates like null dates (not specified) and add these always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @PRICES TABLE (
    SKU nvarchar(10),
    PriceType nvarchar(10),
    FromDate date,
    ToDate date,
    Price int
)

INSERT @PRICES VALUES 
('SUR40'  ,  'NONMEMBER' ,   '1900-01-01'  ,  '1900-01-01'  ,  1000 ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'RSP'        ,  '1900-01-01'  ,  '1900-01-01'  ,  1500 ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'MEMBER'    ,   '2012-07-04'  ,  '2012-07-04'  ,  649  ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'MEMBER'   ,    '2012-06-15'  ,  '2012-06-15' ,   699  ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'MEMBER'   ,    '2012-06-01'  ,  '2012-06-01' ,   599  ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'MEMBER'    ,   '2012-03-31'  ,  '2012-03-31'  ,  699  ) ,
('SUR40'  ,  'MEMBER'     ,  '1900-01-01'  ,  '1900-01-01'   , 749  )
```

Query parameters:

```
DECLARE @SKU nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @Date date

SET @SKU = 'SUR40'
SET @Date = '2012-06-15'
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        SKU,
        PriceType,
        FromDate,
        ToDate,
        Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (
                PARTITION BY SKU, PriceType
                ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN (FromDate = '1900-01-01' 
                      AND ToDate = '1900-01-01') THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
                END ASC) rn
    FROM @PRICES
    WHERE 
        SKU = @SKU
        AND (
            (FromDate = '1900-01-01' AND ToDate = '1900-01-01')
            OR
            (FromDate <= @Date AND @Date <= ToDate)
            )
    ) Raw
WHERE rn = 1
```

Explanation, from the inside out:

- For each SKU and price type, we are interested in both the fallback row and a date-matching row, if there is one
- We want to prefer a date-matching row, so we use `ROW_NUMBER()` with suitable `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` clauses to order the date-matching row (if there is one) in front of the fallback row
- This is the inner, `Raw`, query
- We then merely select all those rows from `Raw` that have rownumber `1`. This will be date-matching rows where they exist, or fallback rows where there is no date-matching row.

Comment: Thanks AakashM! This does exactly what was asked in the question, with detailed explanations to help readers understand what's going on in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Although your second query seems to be buggy(you've omitted the record with price 749 although the dates are `` `1900-01-01 ``), i think you want to return `1900-01-01` dates always:

```
select SKU, PriceType, FromDate, ToDate, Price 
from PRICES
where SKU='SUR40'
and PriceType IN ('NONMEMBER','RSP','MEMBER')
and ((FromDate='1900-01-01' AND ToDate='1900-01-01')
    OR 
     (FromDate>='2012-06-15' AND ToDate<='2012-06-15')
    )
order by PriceType, FromDate DESC
```

Of course you should use parameters above instead of constant values.

Here's the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18cf7/4

Comment: Upvoting for sqlfiddle, never knew about it before. Not returning the 1900-01-01 entry in the second query was intended when I asked the question since I only needed the query to return what price to be displayed given the current date, but still returning the `1900-01-01` prices anyways can be useful for management, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a group by, you just need to add a restriction to the date:

```
select SKU, PriceType, FromDate, ToDate, Price from PRICES
where SKU IN ('SUR40')
and PriceType IN ('NONMEMBER','RSP','MEMBER')
and (FromDate = '1900-01-01' or @dateToProcess between FromDate and ToDate)
order by PriceType, FromDate DESC
```

`@dateToProcess` will be 2012-06-16 or 2012-06-15, etc.

Comment: This will give *two* rows (the date-match and the fallback) for PriceTypes with a date-matching row.

Comment: @AakashM it seemed that's what was intended!